# Use C# to reparse a string already containing asterisk character replacements

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I received a very helpful response to a previous question raised here.

[Use C# to surround phrases in a string with asterisk characters from a dictionary of phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134352/use-c-sharp-to-surround-phrases-in-a-string-with-asterisk-characters-from-a-dict)

I am now posting a follow-up question for a specific issue.

The basic premise for my original query was that I have an array of words and phrases such as the following.

- Flour
- Wheat Flour
- Nut
- Nuts

After processing a string of text such as the following.

```
"Salt, Water, Wheat Flour, Palm Oil, Nuts, Tree Nuts"
```

My goal is to have a string that looks as follows (i.e. the words and phrases from the dictionary are surrounded with asterisk characters, with the longest phrase given priority).

```
"Salt, Water, *Wheat Flour*, Palm Oil, *Nuts*, Tree *Nuts*"
```

The above is achievable by using the following Regex pattern kindly provided by Dmitry Bychenko.

```
  string pattern = @"\b(?<!\*)(?:" + string.Join("|", words
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Length)
    .Select(chunk => Regex.Escape(chunk))) + @")(?!\*)\b";
```

I have a specific question in regards to when the string I am dealing with has already been processed.

Imagine I have a string that has already been processed, such as the following.

```
"Salt, Water, *Wheat Flour*, Palm Oil, *Nuts*, Tree *Nuts*"
```

If the array of words I want to replace within the above string now contains a more specific phrase such as "Tree Nuts" is there a Regex expression that can detect that the following phrase should be replaced?

```
"Tree *Nuts*"
```

i.e. this section of the string should be updated to the following.

```
"*Tree Nuts*"
```

Comment: Remove all asterisks before re-processing the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution, I suggest implementing two stage replacement.

First, let's remove "erroneous" `*`, i.e. let turn any `*word*` into `word`:

```
  string[] words = new string[] {
    "Flour",
    "Wheat Flour",
    "Nut",
    "Nuts",
    "Tree Nuts"
  };

  string removePattern = @"(?:" + string.Join("|", words
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Length)
    .Select(chunk => $@"\*{Regex.Escape(chunk)}\*")) + @")";
```

So given `text` with `*` we can clear it:

```
  string text = "Salt, Water, *Wheat Flour*, Palm Oil, *Nuts*, Tree *Nuts*";

  // unwanted * removed: 
  // "Salt, Water, Wheat Flour, Palm Oil, Nuts, Tree Nuts" 
  string cleared = Regex.Replace(text, removePattern, m => m.Value.Trim('*'));
```

Then (second stage) business as usual:

```
  string pattern = @"\b(?<!\*)(?:" + string.Join("|", words
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Length)
    .Select(chunk => Regex.Escape(chunk))) + @")(?!\*)\b";

  string result = Regex.Replace(cleared, pattern, m => "*" + m.Value + "*");
```

Comment: Thank you once again!